# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified though the exact same file worked previously

Tags: python, environment-variables, geckodriver, file-not-found

I have a python script that previously worked fine but now errors, so I am not sure what happened. I am getting the error that:

```
C:\Users\663255\Desktop>PMI_Tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\663255\Desktop\PMI_Tests.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko+'.exe')
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\663255\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

The start of the file looks like:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser


gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver'))
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko+'.exe')


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

#sets up driver to run tests
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = driver
```

I am unsure why the file stopped working, as it had worked previously many times before. also, both python and geckodriver are definitely defined in the path, but when run via the terminal it says that geckodriver is not in the path.

I have a feeling the issue has to do with the way geckodriver (i.e. gecko variable) is defined in a weird way in the code, or something like that. I have viewed other stack overflow posts with similar problems but have not found anything that fixed my problem. I am using Python 3.6.2 if that is helpful. Any insight would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using windows you can simply add system path through environmental path.   I am having same issue.  Were you able to resolve?  I am using Anaconda in a virtual env.  Chrome works perfectly.  Traditionally putting drivers in an Anaconda folder usually resolves however geckodriver does not utilise this for me.  I am using a headless firefox for windows though.  https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win.   In your case most likely adding drivers to Python directory + updating environmental variables in windows should resolve

Comment: I was not using anaconda.  ended up redefining the gecko variable to hard code it's path, which did end up solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to this problem, I hardcoded the full path to geckodriver in the gecko variable, instead of trying to dynamically locate it. I am unsure why the dynamic approach stopped working, but hardcoding the filepath fixed any issues for me.